# Split String from Serial Port in Java

Tags: java, string, split, serial-port

I have an arduino code that sends the millis() and two readings from two potentiometers, they are each sent on a new line like so:

```
 Serial.println(millis());
 Serial.println(val1);
 Serial.println(val2);
```

I want to use java to store each of those string in its own variable so I can use JFreeChart to graph the data and see it live, however I'm having trouble placing the strings into separate variables.

I tried changing the arduino code and using the String split method in java but that did not work.

here is the part of my code where I use the Scanner to read the Serial data:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            //where the data stuff is put into graph
        }
        scan.close();
    }
};
```

**edit:**

so I tried using the split method like so:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String serialDat;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            serialDat = scan.next();
            String[] dataValues = serialDat.split(",");
            System.out.println(dataValues[0] + " " + dataValues[1] + " " + dataValues[2]);

        }
        scan.close();
    }
};
```

I made the arduino send the data like this through Serial : millis(),sensor1,sensor2

but when I use the java code and connect to the port I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
```

Comment: What's the actual issue you're having?

Comment: basically I want to put the data from arduino into a java graph, but I can't separate the data as arduino sends in everything as one string.

Comment: I'm asking what the actual *issue* is--I know what you're trying to do. We can't see your data, we don't know how you're trying to split anything, etc. There's nothing here we can work with.

Comment: My issue is when I split the data I get the array out of bounds exception

Comment: Show your data. The error message is quite clear, but we can't see your data, and you're insistent on not providing it, so nobody can help.

Comment: here is what the arduino sends: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i_Itc19GIJUTb_VCXhjlnYTXyMwz76r_

Comment: So, millis() value is always an integer, sensor1 and sensor2 values are always double or float, correct @UjwalJoshi ? If that is the case, the solution would be straightforward. I will modify my answer based on this.

Comment: @Ashish that is correct

Comment: Thank you. Also, one more question @UjwalJoshi - Will it always be 3 values separated by a coma?

Comment: yes @Ashish, just the millis, sensor 1 and sensor 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of strings like String[] if the number of inputs is known beforehand. Even if it’s not known, you can use a List as input for these strings.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import com.google.common.base.Strings;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class StackOverflow_56719783 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StackOverflow_56719783.class.getSimpleName());

        //Use the port.getInputStream() instead of the file. I used file as you had given access to the
        //file in google drive present in the local machine.
        File inputFile = new File("XXXXX/inputfile.txt");
        //The FileInputStream is used in place of port.getInputStream() here.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        String serialData;
        //Use scan.hasNext() instead of scan.hasNextLine(). Please check the JavaDocs for
        //both these methods for the reason.
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            serialData = scan.next();
            //Check if the current line is an empty line - Strings class is from google's guava library
            //https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21
            if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(serialData)) {
                continue;
            }

            //If current string does not contain the delimiter at all, we continue.
            if(!serialData.contains(",")) {
                logger.info("The input line does not contain the de-limiter ,");
                continue;
            }
            //Now we continue to split
            String[] dataValues = serialData.split(",");
            //If should be true that the length of the split array is greater than 0 and equal to 3.
            //Going by your input values, the first value looks like to be always an integer, second value is a double, third value is also a double.
            if(dataValues.length > 0 && dataValues.length == 3) {
                int millis = Integer.parseInt(dataValues[0]);
                double sensor1 = Double.parseDouble(dataValues[1]);
                double sensor2 = Double.parseDouble(dataValues[2]);
                System.out.println(millis + " "+ sensor1 + " "+sensor2);
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this and got the array out of bounds exception

Comment: @UjwalJoshi - Please check my edited code above. It should solve your problem. Please check out the comments in the code to get proper clarifications on what I have done. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you it works, when I disconnect from serial port it gives me nosuchelementexception at line 51 which is the line that says: serialData = scan.next() but I don't think that will be that big of a problemI'll research and try and fix that if I can